# I have Class file which has multiple methods, Can i invoke the class from Testcase

Tags: java, class, methods, junit, testcase

I have a class called `TestingClass` and I have a one more class called `TestCase` .

In `TestingClass` I have 4 methods which are dependent on each other, Can i call the this class file from my `TestCase` file and invoke all the methods at once?

Comment: Only you can answer that... Unless you provide some more information like what you mean with calling all methods at once and if your are asking if it is possible from a technical point of view or more like best practices and of course some code would probably help.

Comment: Can you show us your code? Otherwise it's hard to help you

Comment: This is a hardware dependent problem. If you expect to call 4 methods at once you need at least 4 cores and even then there's no absolute certainty they'll be executed concurrently if one of the cores are busy doing something else.

Comment: In theory you could make a secondary wrapper function for each of your 4 functions which would block (infinite loop) based on a volatile property until all 4 are ready but it would likely block forever if you had less than 4 cores.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with extend the `TestingClass` and overwriting those methods as like,

```
public class TestCase extends TestingClass {
    @Override
    public void method1(){
       super.method1();
    }

    @Override
    public void method2(){
       super.method2();
    }

    @Override
    public void method3(){
       super.method3();
    }

    @Override
    public void method4(){
       super.method4();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can if they have visibility.

In your `TestCase` you have to declarate a variable of `TestingClass` and instantiate it. Then, if your methods are `public` you can use them.

Here is an example:

```
public class TestCase {

     private TestingClass testingClass = new TestingClass();

     @Test
     public void test1(){
         testingClass.methodFromTestCase();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do it, refer below example:

```
            package overridefunction;
            public class SuperClass 
                {
                public void method1()
                {
                    System.out.println("superclass method1");
                    this.method2();
                    this.method3();
                    this.method4();
                    this.method5();
                }
                public void method2()
                {
                    System.out.println("superclass method2");
                }
                private void method3()
                {
                    System.out.println("superclass method3");
                }
                protected void method4()
                {
                    System.out.println("superclass method4");
                }
                void method5()
                {
                    System.out.println("superclass method5");
                }
            }

        package overridefunction1;
            public class SubClass extends SuperClass
            {
                @Override
                public void method1()
                {
                    System.out.println("subclass method1");
                    super.method1();
                }
            }

            
            package overridefunction1;
            public class Demo 
            {
                public static void main(String[] args) 
                {
                    SubClass mSubClass = new SubClass();
                    mSubClass.method1();
                }
            }

            subclass method1
            superclass method1
            superclass method2
            superclass method3
            superclass method4
            superclass method5
```